# Finding what methods a Python object has

Tags: python, introspection

Given a Python object of any kind, is there an easy way to get the list of all methods that this object has?

Or if this is not possible, is there at least an easy way to check if it has a particular method, other than checking if an error occurs when the method is called?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46033277/1959808

Answer (score 758, accepted):

**For many objects**, you can use this code, replacing 'object' with the object you're interested in:

```py
object_methods = [method_name for method_name in dir(object)
                  if callable(getattr(object, method_name))]
```

I discovered it at [diveintopython.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20180901124519/http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html) (now archived), that should provide some further details!

**If you get an `AttributeError`, you can use this instead**:

`getattr()` is intolerant of pandas style Python 3.6 abstract virtual sub-classes.  This code does the same as above and ignores exceptions.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]],
                  columns=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
def get_methods(object, spacing=20):
  methodList = []
  for method_name in dir(object):
    try:
        if callable(getattr(object, method_name)):
            methodList.append(str(method_name))
    except Exception:
        methodList.append(str(method_name))
  processFunc = (lambda s: ' '.join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
  for method in methodList:
    try:
        print(str(method.ljust(spacing)) + ' ' +
              processFunc(str(getattr(object, method).__doc__)[0:90]))
    except Exception:
        print(method.ljust(spacing) + ' ' + ' getattr() failed')

get_methods(df['foo'])
```

Comment: It's a list comprehension, returning a list of methods where method is an item in the list returned by dir(object), and where each method is added to the list only if getattr(object,method) returns a callable.

Comment: @marsh To print the methods: `print [method for method in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, method))]`.

Comment: I'm getting an `AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.common' has no attribute 'AbstractMethodError'` when I try to run this. See details at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54713287/9677043.

Comment: To exclude dunder methods:   `[ m for m in dir(object) if not m.startswith('__')]`

Comment: Other way using filter:

`print(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != '_' and callable(getattr(obj, x)), dir(obj))))`

Comment: Though such things are not common, this will return callable instance attributes that are not methods. A method results from calling a *class* attribute from an instance. Also, `dir` is not a reliable way to get *all* attributes of an object; most significantly, a class can define what `dir` returns by overriding `__dir__`.

Answer (score 369):

You can use the built in `dir()` function to get a list of all the attributes a module has.  Try this at the command line to see how it works.

```
>>> import moduleName
>>> dir(moduleName)
```

Also, you can use the `hasattr(module_name, "attr_name")` function to find out if a module has a specific attribute.

See the [Python introspection](https://zetcode.com/python/introspection/) for more information.

Comment: The "Guide to Python Introspection" link seems to be dead.

Comment: @Loveandpeace-JoeCodeswell Thank you. I couldn't find the original resource, so I had to update it with a link to a different article.

Answer (score 157):

The simplest method is to use `dir(objectname)`. It will display all the methods available for that object.

Comment: It also displays the attributes of the object, so if you want to specifically find methods, it will not work.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. But, I am not aware of any other technique to only get the list of methods. Maybe the best idea is to get the list of both attributes and methods and then use <hasattr(object, "method_name"> to further filter it out?

Comment: @neuronet, I'm trying to run the accepted answer but getting an `AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.common' has no attribute 'AbstractMethodError'`. Any ideas? See deets at  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54713287/9677043. +1 to @Pawan Kumar b/c the answer works, and to @ljs for the promise of a filtered list of just the methods.

Answer (score 42):

I believe that you want something like this:

> a list of attributes from an object

The built-in function `dir()` can do this job.

Taken from `help(dir)` output on your Python shell:

> dir(...)
>
> ```
> dir([object]) -> list of strings
> ```
>
> If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
>
> Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
>
> If the object supplies a method named `__dir__`, it will be used; otherwise
> the default dir() logic is used and returns:
>
> - for a module object: the module's attributes.
> - for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes of its bases.
> - for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.

**For example:**

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> a = "I am a string"
>>>
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>>
>>> dir(a)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__',
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__',
'__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
'__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__',
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__',
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
'_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize',
'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find',
'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace',
'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition',
'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip',
'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title',
'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

Answer (score 35):

To check if it has a particular method:

```
hasattr(object,"method")
```

Comment: since the OP is looking for a method and not just and attribute, I think you want to go a step further with: `if hasattr(obj,method) and callable(getattr(obj,method)):`

Answer (score 29):

The simplest way to get a list of methods of any object is to use the `help()` command.

```
help(object)
```

It will list out all the available/important methods associated with that object.

For example:

```
help(str)
```

Answer (score 28):

On top of the more direct answers, I'd be remiss if I didn't mention [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/).

Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see the available methods, with autocompletion.

And once you've found a method, try:

```
help(object.method)
```

to see the pydocs, method signature, etc.

Ahh... [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL).

Answer (score 26):

Suppose we have a Python `obj`. Then to see all the methods it has, including those surrounded by `__` ([magic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690287/4317058)):

```
print(dir(obj))
```

To exclude magic builtins one would do:

```
[m for m in dir(obj) if not m.startswith('__')]
```

Answer (score 21):

If you specifically want **methods**, you should use [inspect.ismethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod).

For method names:

```
import inspect
method_names = [attr for attr in dir(self) if inspect.ismethod(getattr(self, attr))]
```

For the methods themselves:

```
import inspect
methods = [member for member in [getattr(self, attr) for attr in dir(self)] if inspect.ismethod(member)]
```

Sometimes [`inspect.isroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isroutine) can be useful too (for built-ins, C extensions, Cython without the "binding" compiler directive).

Comment: Shouldn't you use [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) instead of using `dir` in a list comprehension?

Comment: `inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod)` ?

Answer (score 16):

Open a Bash shell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on Ubuntu). Start a Python 3 shell in it. Create an object to observe the methods of. Just add a dot after it and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice and you'll see something like this:

```
user@note:~$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import readline
>>> readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
>>> s = "Any object. Now it's a string"
>>> s. # here tab should be pressed twice
s.__add__(           s.__rmod__(          s.istitle(
s.__class__(         s.__rmul__(          s.isupper(
s.__contains__(      s.__setattr__(       s.join(
s.__delattr__(       s.__sizeof__(        s.ljust(
s.__dir__(           s.__str__(           s.lower(
s.__doc__            s.__subclasshook__(  s.lstrip(
s.__eq__(            s.capitalize(        s.maketrans(
s.__format__(        s.casefold(          s.partition(
s.__ge__(            s.center(            s.replace(
s.__getattribute__(  s.count(             s.rfind(
s.__getitem__(       s.encode(            s.rindex(
s.__getnewargs__(    s.endswith(          s.rjust(
s.__gt__(            s.expandtabs(        s.rpartition(
s.__hash__(          s.find(              s.rsplit(
s.__init__(          s.format(            s.rstrip(
s.__iter__(          s.format_map(        s.split(
s.__le__(            s.index(             s.splitlines(
s.__len__(           s.isalnum(           s.startswith(
s.__lt__(            s.isalpha(           s.strip(
s.__mod__(           s.isdecimal(         s.swapcase(
s.__mul__(           s.isdigit(           s.title(
s.__ne__(            s.isidentifier(      s.translate(
s.__new__(           s.islower(           s.upper(
s.__reduce__(        s.isnumeric(         s.zfill(
s.__reduce_ex__(     s.isprintable(
s.__repr__(          s.isspace(
```

Comment: While we're talking about workarounds like this, I'll add that you can also run `ipython`, start typing the object and press `tab` and it'll work as well.  No readline settings needed

Comment: @MaxCoplan I've added the workaround in code for cases where tab-completion  is not enabled by default

Answer (score 11):

The problem with all methods indicated here is that you *can't* be sure that a method doesn't exist.

In Python you can intercept the dot calling through `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`, making it possible to create method "at runtime"

Example:

```
class MoreMethod(object):
    def some_method(self, x):
        return x
    def __getattr__(self, *args):
        return lambda x: x*2
```

If you execute it, you can call non-existing methods in the object dictionary...

```
>>> o = MoreMethod()
>>> o.some_method(5)
5
>>> dir(o)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'some_method']
>>> o.i_dont_care_of_the_name(5)
10
```

And it's why you use the [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) paradigms in Python.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reliable way to list all object's methods. `dir(object)` is usually useful, but in some cases it may not list all methods. According to [`dir()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir): *"With an argument, **attempt** to return a list of valid attributes for that object."*

Checking that method exists can be done by `callable(getattr(object, method))` as already mentioned there.

Answer (score 4):

```py
import moduleName
for x in dir(moduleName):
    print(x)
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 3):

I have done the following function (`get_object_functions`), which receives an object (`object_`) as its argument, and **returns a list (`functions`) containing all of the methods (including static and class methods) defined in the object's class**:

```py
def get_object_functions(object_):
    functions = [attr_name
                 for attr_name in dir(object_)
                 if str(type(getattr(object_,
                                     attr_name))) in ("<class 'function'>",
                                                      "<class 'method'>")]
    return functions
```

Well, it just checks if the string representation of the type of a class' attribute equals `"<class 'function'>"` or `"<class 'method'>"` and then includes that attribute in the `functions` list if that's `True`.

---

#### Demo

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def introduce(self):
        print(f'My name is {self.name}')

    @staticmethod
    def say_hi():
        print('hi')

    @classmethod
    def reproduce(cls, name):
        return cls(name, 0)


person = Person('Rafael', 27)
print(get_object_functions(person))
```

#### Output

```py
['__init__', 'introduce', 'reproduce', 'say_hi']
```

*For a cleaner version of the code:* https://github.com/revliscano/utilities/blob/master/get_object_functions/object_functions_getter.py

Answer (score 2):

> ...is there at least an easy way to check if it has a particular method other than simply checking if an error occurs when the method is called

While "[Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)" is certainly the Pythonic way, you may be looking for:

```
d={'foo':'bar', 'spam':'eggs'}
if 'get' in dir(d):
    d.get('foo')
# OUT: 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

One can create a `getAttrs` function that will return an object's callable property names

```
def getAttrs(object):
  return filter(lambda m: callable(getattr(object, m)), dir(object))

print getAttrs('Foo bar'.split(' '))
```

That'd return

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__',
 '__delslice__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
 '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', 
 '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', 
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', 
 '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
 '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 
 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a list as an object

```
obj = []
```

`list(filter(lambda x:callable(getattr(obj,x)),obj.__dir__()))`

You get:

```
['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__iadd__',
 '__imul__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__reversed__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'append',
 'clear',
 'copy',
 'count',
 'extend',
 'index',
 'insert',
 'pop',
 'remove',
 'reverse',
 'sort']
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to search for a specific method in a whole module

```
for method in dir(module) :
  if "keyword_of_methode" in method :
   print(method, end="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are, for instance, using shell plus you can use this instead:

```
>> MyObject??
```

that way, with the '??' just after your object, it'll show you all the attributes/methods the class has.

Comment: What is *"shell plus"*?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of dir() which is pre-defined in Python.

```
import module_name
dir(module_name)
```

You can also pass an object to dir() as

```
dir(object_name)
```

If the object is an object of a pre-defined class such as int, str, etc. it displays the methods in it (you may know those methods as built in functions). If that object is created for a user-defined class, it displays all the methods given in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, I want to see the user-defined methods and I don't want to see the built-in attributes that start with '__', if you want that you can use the following code:

```
object_methods = [method_name for method_name in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, method_name)) and '__' not in method_name]
```

For example, for this class:

```
class Person: 
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name 
    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)
```

Above code will print: ['print_name']

Answer (score -1):

Here's a nice one liner (but will get attributes as well):

```
print(*dir(obj), sep='\n')
```