# How to use pythons map with a non-iterable and iterable set of parameters?

Tags: python

To make a simple example, I don't care about the practicality, just the implemenation.  Say I create some class with a few methods. I want to create a list containing whether or not they're callable.  So I can take this example from:
[Finding what methods an object has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-the-methods-an-object-has)

```
[method for method in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, method))]
```

It's great for what it does, but if for the heck of it, I want to use map and I have object, which is a non-iterable item...

```
map(callable,map(getattr,object,dir(object)))
```

**To focus on the real problem:**

I have an iterable list, and a non iterable item.  What is the best solution that lets me use some non-iterable item and an iterable item, so that I can utilize map?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking or what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Falmarri: You're not alone.  This seems more a riddle than a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will admit to not understanding why, since the LC works, but:

```
map(lambda x: callable(getattr(object, x)), dir(object))
```

Comment: Awesome.  Just what I wanted.  Thanks : )

Comment: Different application, I just pulled that as an example. I wanted to use map w/ a few non-iterable items.

Comment: The main reason for the question was to try some optimizations.  Interestingly enough, the LC was actually faster when running through a longer sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not clear on what the lambda above does, equivalently you could define:

```
def myMap(fun1,obj,iterlist):
        def fun2(x):
            return fun1(obj,x)
        return map(fun2,iterlist)
```

And then, call

```
map(callable,myMap(getattr,object,dir(object)))
```

for example:

```
map(callable,myMap(getattr,myMap,dir(myMap)))
```

Though using lambda is more pythonic.

Comment: "Though using lambda is more pythonic." ... according to who?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime LC is just the right way to do it

```
>>> from itertools import izip, repeat, starmap
>>> map(callable, starmap(getattr, zip(repeat(object), dir(object))))
```

This also works, but requires `dir(object)` twice

```
>>> map(callable, map(getattr, repeat(object, len(dir(object))), dir(object)))
```

and finally

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> map(callable, starmap(getattr, izip_longest([], dir(object), fillvalue=object)))
```