# find all members of an instance in python, excluding __init__

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, introspection

the `vars` key word gives me all the variables in an instance, for example:

```
In [245]: vars(a)
Out[245]: {'propa': 0, 'propb': 1}
```

However, I am not aware of a single solution to list all callable members which are defined in my class (see for example here: [Finding what methods an object has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-what-methods-an-object-has)), I added this simple improvements which excludes `__init__`:

```
In [244]: [method for method in dir(a) if callable(getattr(a, method)) and not method.startswith('__')]
Out[244]: ['say']
```

Compare to:

```
In [243]: inspect.getmembers(a)
Out[243]:
[('__class__', __main__.syncher),
 ('__delattr__',
  <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>),
 ('__dict__', {'propa': 0, 'propb': 1}),
 ('__doc__', None),
 ...snipped ...
 ('__format__', <function __format__>),
 ('__getattribute__',
  <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>),
 ('__hash__', <method-wrapper '__hash__' of syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>),
 ('__init__', <bound method syncher.__init__ of <__main__.syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>>),
 ('__module__', '__main__'),
 ('__setattr__',
  <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>),
 ('__weakref__', None),
 ('propa', 0),
 ('propb', 1),
 ('say', <bound method syncher.say of <__main__.syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>>)]
```

or for example:

```
In [248]: [method for method in dir(a) if callable(getattr(a, method)) 
                and isinstance(getattr(a, method), types.MethodType)]
Out[248]: ['__init__', 'say']
```

and I also found this method, which excludes the built-in routines:

```
In [258]: inspect.getmembers(a, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
Out[258]:
[('__init__',
  <bound method syncher.__init__ of <__main__.syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>>),
 ('say', <bound method syncher.say of <__main__.syncher object at 0xd6d9dd0>>)]
```

So, my question is: 
    do you have a better way to find all methods inside a class (excluding `__init__`, and all the built-in methods) in Python 2.7.X ?

Comment: That solution looks rather elegant to me, is the performance not meeting your needs? otherwise, I'd say stick to it.

Comment: @coder543, I don't have a problem with the performance. I just wondered if my search for a "Python Zen" was done ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else offered a better solution, I guess the Pythonic way would be to with Python's STL:

```
inspect.getmembers(a, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
```

To exclude init one can use `filter`.