# Can i get all methods of a python object?

Tags: python

I want to get every methods of an object. I know about the function `dir` but it returns all(method, attr, meta_data).

I tried this:

```
[x for x in dir(obj) if "_" not in x]
```

but it does not work correctly.

How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding what methods an object has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-what-methods-an-object-has)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need see  [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html). For example

```
inspect.getmembers(object, inspect.ismethod)
```

it returns only method.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter `dir` result

```
[method for method in dir(obj) if callable(getattr(obj, method))]
```