# How to find method implementation using Eclipse Pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, class, methods, pydev

I'm look over some code at  work and I have a member method that is being called. However the the class of the object does not contain the implementation nor the prototype for the method. The Eclipse debugger doesn't work for me and `pdb.set_trace()` isn't stopping at the function. Does anyone know how I can find the member method?

```
self.confirmTrue(object.memberMethod())
```

Comment: Try something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34452/1401034) to see all methods associated with your object?

Comment: For some reason the method is not showing up as an association with the object. But some how the code still compiles runs. How is this possible?