# How to know all the operations which we can able to perform on list in python?

Tags: python, list

While working with lists sometimes I got "list object has no attribute" type of results.So I think it's better to know which are the in-built operations we can
perform on list.

Comment: Check out the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for list.

Comment: `dir(list)` will enumerate all the methods available on `list` objects

Comment: The canonical way: reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). You can also directly inspect the object's documentation from the REPL: `help(list)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding what methods a Python object has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-what-methods-a-python-object-has)

Answer (score 2):

There are two primary ways to do this.

1. Use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) to list all the attributes related to an object.

   > attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object

   ```
   >>> dir(list)
   => ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__',
       '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
       '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__',
       '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__',
       '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
       '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', 
       '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
       '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 
       'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
   ```
2. Use [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) to get a consorted list of all the related functions, attributes etc.

   > Invoke the built-in help system

   ```
   >>> help([])

   Help on list object:

   class list(object)
   |  list() -> new empty list
   |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
   |  
   |  Methods defined here:
   |  
   |  __add__(self, value, /)
   |      Return self+value.
   |  
   |  __contains__(self, key, /)
   |      Return key in self.
   |  
   |  __delitem__(self, key, /)
   |      Delete self[key].
   |  
   |  __eq__(self, value, /)
   |      Return self==value.

   ... and so on
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can run [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) on your list object to get the attributes.

```
dir([])
```

Will show:

```
 ['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__iadd__',
 '__imul__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__reversed__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'append',
 'clear',
 'copy',
 'count',
 'extend',
 'index',
 'insert',
 'pop',
 'remove',
 'reverse',
 'sort']
```