# How do I access and print out an entire class variable in Python?

Tags: python, csv, class

I am just learning about classes in python and am having a little trouble understanding them. I have this code that reads a CSV file into a class. An example of some of the class names from the file are Age, Education, Gender, Salary, etc. I am wanting to be able to access and print out everything from say the Age variable. I know I can print a specific element with `print(instances[1].Age)`, but the list has many elements and I would like to be able to access all of them. I am thinking a for loop would work but I am unsure as to how to write it.

```
 class File:
    def __init__(self, row, header):
        self.__dict__ = dict(zip(header, row))
data = list(csv.reader(open('data_file.csv')))
instances = [File(i, data[0]) for i in data[1:]]
```

This is what I have to read the CSV file into the class, from here I am having trouble accessing the variables.

Comment: are you asked to use **class** in this challenge? coz it will be much easier to  use **with open** and for loop.

Comment: I can use **with open** but it was stated that using **class** was preferred. I have managed to make it work using the **with open** method but I'm still open to ideas for the other way.

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` will list everything a `module` has.

```
class B:
    x = 5
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
        
    def method(self):
        print("world")
        
        
b  = B();
print(dir(B))

objectMethods =  [] #stores methods
objectMemberVars = [] #stores member variables as tuples (name,value)
for attr in dir(b):
    if callable(getattr(b,attr)):
        objectMethods.append(getattr(b,attr)) 
    else:
        objectMemberVars.append((attr,getattr(b,attr)))
        
print(objectMethods)
print(objectMemberVars)
print(objectMethods[1])
```

output :

```
hello
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'method', 'x']
[<bound method B.__init__ of <__main__.B instance at 0x7fc3afa41320>>, <bound method B.method of <__main__.B instance at 0x7fc3afa41320>>]
[('__doc__', None), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('x', 5)]
<bound method B.method of <__main__.B instance at 0x7fc3afa41320>>
```

You can do this for class definitions and instances. The difference is that methods of class definitions are represented as `unbound` while methods of instances are `bound`

I referenced this post:
[Finding what methods a Python object has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-what-methods-a-python-object-has/37464502)

Answer (score 0):

I made this answer on the base of the following csv file example

> title,name,date,age,feedback
>
> Great Customer Service,John,2017-12-21,25,The customer service here is
> very good. They helped me find a 2017 Camry with good condition in
> reasonable price. Compared to other dealers, they provided the lowest
> price. Definitely recommend!

Since you are not forced to use class, it's much easier to do the job with list.

```
import csv


with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/folder/log.csv') as f:

    data = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for rows in reader:
      data.append(rows)
    for row in data:
        print(row['age'])
```

output

25